# repeated GET requests in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, http-get

I have this weird issue going on where multiple get requests are being made even if all the info in the view is already loaded.

[image: get]

I used Bennadel's examples to create my $http services: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm

Here's my service code:
[image: service]

And controller code:
[image: ctrl]

Am I missing something that is allowing the get methods to prop? Should only be executed once on page load and not numerous times. Thanks in advance for your keen eyes and help.

Comment: see if it is getting called from HTML

Comment: @maddog vm.initData() only executes on page load from the controller--there's no where else in the html view where that function is called

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a controller in routing (in my case I was using ui-router) AND within your directives--in my case the call to http-get multiple times was caused by this issue. I just removed controllerAs and controller options from my directives and the issue was fixed. I'm pretty new to creating component directives so I'm glad I can move on from this lol.